# MVC Post collections are empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Update:**
The real problem was in 2 parts.

1. the model needs properties, not fields (i.e. get and set)
2. when calling Html.BeginCollectionItem("Something")), make **sure** that something does not match a class name, or a property name. It really messes up the script.

Hopefully this might save someone else the grief I just had to deal with.

*

I'm trying to implement the code from Steven Sanderson's blog post [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)
but my data is structured differently, with the collection inside a wrapper class.

Despite my best efforts, my post always comes back empty. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new GiftWrapper();
        model.Id = 46;
        model.Gifts= new[] {
            new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
            new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
        }.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(GiftWrapper model)
    {
        return View("Completed", model);
    }

    public ViewResult Add()
    {
        return View("GiftEditorRow", new Gift());
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class GiftWrapper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Gift> Gifts;
}
public class Gift
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EditorDemo.Models.GiftWrapper>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EditorDemo.Helpers"%>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <div id="editorRows">
            <% foreach (var item in Model.Gifts)
                Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
            %>
        </div>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" }) %>

        <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
    <% } %>       
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Model to these:

```
public class GiftWrapper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
}
public class Gift
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb for not noticing that. Thanks Armen!

Comment: Lolll... I know... it always happen ... sometimes we need one more eye! :)